# C# TcpListener not listening

Tags: c#, winforms, networking, tcp, tcplistener

I tried implementing the code given [here](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/a/78346/136554). But I'm not able to connect to the device. The client device is working fine, as I tried using another software which is able to read data from it.

I have the following code:

```
    private void ReceivePortMessages()
    {
        _TcpListener = new TcpListener(IPAddress.Any, 23);

        byte[] receiveBuffer = new byte[6400];
        while (!_QuitProcessing)
        {
            int requestCount = 0;
            _TcpListener.Start();
            Console.WriteLine(" >> Listener Started");

            using (var tcpClient = _TcpListener.AcceptTcpClient())
            {
                Console.WriteLine(" >> Accepted connection from client");

                using (var networkStream = tcpClient.GetStream())
                {
                    while (!_QuitProcessing)
                    {
                        try
                        {
                            requestCount = requestCount++;
                            var bytesRead = networkStream.Read(receiveBuffer, 0, (int)tcpClient.ReceiveBufferSize);
                            if (bytesRead == 0)
                            {
                                // Read returns 0 if the client closes the connection
                                break;
                            }

                            string dataFromClient = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(receiveBuffer, 0, bytesRead);
                            Console.WriteLine(dataFromClient);

                        }
                        catch (Exception ex)
                        {
                            Console.WriteLine("ReceivePortMessages: " + ex.ToString());
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                }
                Console.WriteLine(" >> stopped read loop");
            }
            _TcpListener.Stop();
        }
    }
```

and I'm calling it using:

```
Thread thread = new Thread(ReceivePortMessages);
thread.IsBackground = true;
thread.Start();
```

It prints `>> Listener Started`. Nothing is printed after that.

The `AcceptTcpClient()` never gets called.

Can anyone please tell me how to solve this ?

Also I would like to know when the other software can connect to the device using it's IP address, why does my program throw the following error when I use an IP like `IPAddress.Parse("192.168.0.100")` instead of `IPAddress.Any` :

> TCP Client:Exception: The requested address is not valid in its context

**Edit #1**

This is for `Winforms`. So basically I have a barcode reader which throws data on ethernet. I want to read this data in my program. Currently, I'm just trying to connect to it and print the values in `Console`. Here is a link to my current code:

[Link to gist](https://gist.github.com/mridah/639d00464d7edd00dc307cc8b8833d86)

Comment: We need a *bit* more context around the call site you've shown. Where is that code running? What type of program is this (console app, forms, service, asp.net, etc)? Ideally, create a [mcve]

Comment: @Damien_The_Unbeliever sorry for the incomplete question. I've updated my question to answer your questions

Comment: 23 is a well known port reserved for telnet. Try another port?

Comment: @kennyzx I tested using Hercules Setup Utility. It's showing the data on port 23 only

Comment: The device is the listener.  You cannot have two listeners talking to each other.  You need to implement a client application and connect to the device using the device IP addrress (not IP.Any).  IP.Any is used only for a listener, not a client.

Comment: @jdweng can you please provide an example ?

Comment: See msdn examples : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/network-programming/socket-code-examples